# PHP pg_query not executing

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have this problem in PostgreSQL where I am parsing a webpages meta tags and then inputing the requesting into pg_query. For purposes of brevity in this example, the data in not sanitized.

So something like this:

```
foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    $property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
    $content = $meta->getAttribute('content');

$query = "UPDATE " . $tablename . " SET article_meta = article_meta || '$property=>$content'::hstore where article_id = '{$this -> article_id}' ;";

pg_query($conn, $query);

}
```

The problem is, the query do not execute nor do they fail or throw any errors. But if I copy the query that was executed and run it through something like pgadmin, it works. So the query is not invalid. Any ideas of why this is happening?

I should mention this behavior may have started when I added a trigger to update a full text search tsvector, but I do not see how this is related.

Update

Also I want to add that I have a sync function that is ru later but only executes the parsing of the meta tags, and the query works. So somewhere something is blocking the query from executing.

Comment: are you sure? I don't see any debugging in your code? use `echo pg_last_error($dbconn);` and check again...

Comment: This is an excerpt, there is debugging because whenever a query fails it does alert me.

Comment: _But if I copy the query..._ Just to be sure. Where did you copy the query from? Did you `echo $query`?

Comment: Yes, I do echo it, copy and paste it into pgphpadmin

Comment: Is there a problem to add it to the question? Obfuscated?

Comment: There are many years that I don't write PHP. Don't you need to explicitly close the connection to commit the changes? Do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you say the block of data is being run, because you can echo the query to the screen and it runs.  This narrows down the possibilities considerably.

The most likely case in my mind is just that you are forgetting to commit your transaction.  Try:

```
pg_query('commit');
```

after the loop.  this may solve your problem.

Another possibility is that the connection is closed, but normally IME at least a warning is thrown in that case.   You may want to try some select queries on the same connection to make sure it is open just to be sure.

Finally you may want to try to use a network analyser to watch for traffic to/from the db (assuming you aren't using local sockets).  This should give you a closer idea of what exactly is happening.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Is there any performance issues I should be worried about? Should a commit be called after each query in general?

Comment: Do a commit where you have reached a point where you want all your statements to roll back or commit as a block.  There is a slight performance cost but it is minor.  So for example you may want to make sure that a bunch of things all happen together or don't happen at all.  The commit goes at the end of that series.

Comment: You only need COMMIT when you start a transaction using BEGIN or START TRANSACTION.